# how to use required validation in primeNg dropdown and form.invalid in button

Tags: angular

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClrSentSubmit()">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="CLRFN_TYPE_DESC">CLRFN_TYPE_DESC</label>
    <div>
        <p-dropdown [options]="clrfnTypeList" required="true" id="CLRFN_REQ_drop" #CLRFN_REQ_drop="ngModel"
            name="CLRFN_REQ_drop" [showTransitionOptions]="'200ms'" [hideTransitionOptions]="'200ms'"
            optionLabel="name" [(ngModel)]="selected_clrfn_sent" [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"></p-dropdown>
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="CLRFN_REQUIRED">CLRFN_REQUIRED</label>
        <input type="text" pInputText id="CLRFN_REQUIRED" required minlength="4" maxlength="240"
            [(ngModel)]="bomhdr_clrfn_sent_value.CLRFN_REQUIRED" #CLRFN_REQUIRED="ngModel" name="CLRFN_REQUIRED"
            class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-helper-clearfix">
            <button type="submit" pButton [disabled]="form.invalid" icon="pi pi-check" label="Save"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

i Want the button to be enabled only when the user gives value for dropdown and gives value input field...

problem is button was enabled after user gives value for input field without choosing dropdown..

required validaton not worked for dropdown ..

thank you

Comment: it looks like you dont have proper validations in the form.

Comment: it is template driven form not reactive form